# Vscode: How to disable auto breaking too long lines?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have line of code:

```
thread = ThreadModel.objects.filter(user=request.user, receiver=receiver)[0]
```

After ctrl + s, Vscode correcting my line and I got:

```
  thread = ThreadModel.objects.filter(
      user=request.user, receiver=receiver)[0]
```

I don't want that. How can I turn off it?

I have read settings and I didn't find solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VsCode settings set `editor.formatOnSave` to `false`

Answer (score 0):

This is because your setting.json is set to automatically format the document when saving. You can type `Ctrl + P` to open setting.json.Set the line `"editor.formatOnSave": false,`However, you should note that if you do this, it will not be formatted automatically when you save. You can manually enter `Ctrl + Shift + P` ,find the select"Format Document".